# VSTS REST Api to create Tasks

Tags: visual-studio, rest, api, tfs, azure-devops

I'm working on creating a VSTS Workitem(Task) using REST API. I'm referencing the below rest api **POST** [https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=5.0-preview.3](https://%7BaccountName%7D.visualstudio.com/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wit/workitems/$%7Btype%7D?api-version=5.0-preview.3)

On the above API, how can I pass the input to **${type}**. Say if I want to create a **Task**, how can I pass the value. I'm using the below body as mentioned in the document.

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
]
```

When I try this, I'm getting **404** error. Looking for the help to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep `$` symbol in the request.

Such as to add a Task work item, you can use below REST API:

```
POST https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=5.0-preview.3
```

application/json-patch+json:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
]
```

Comment: Got it resolved. I used project as **defaultCollection** in Get Workitem call and which was not working when I perform **POST** operation. I need to pass actual Project name. Little confused.

Comment: @S.Siva Add `defaultCollection` can also be working. And the project name is necessary when creating a work item :)

Comment: Yeah got it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the `{type}` in the URL, as well as other tokens in the sample: `{accountName}` and `{project}`:

- When you log in to your VSTS account, the `{accountName}` is the value in the URL before `.visualstudio.com`
- The `{project}` is the name of your team project in VSTS. Again, if you browse it in the browser, the `{project}` is the part of the URL between `visualstudio.com/` and the subsequent `/`
- The `{type}` should be `task` if you want to create tasks

Most info is [here in the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/create?view=vsts-rest-5.0).